# How Create a Down Triangle Like Arrow After Divs In Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i wrote blew menu. and now i want to create arrow button when i hover in each li.but the code does not work correctly. the css codes does not work coorectly and the arrow not shows in the bottom of div that i hovered...

here is my snippet :

```css
/* body layout */
body {
 background:#1b1c20;
}

/* flat mega menu layout start */
.Flat_mega_menu ul,
.Flat_mega_menu li,
.Flat_mega_menu a,
.Flat_mega_menu p,
.Flat_mega_menu i {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
}

/* mega menu layout */
.Flat_mega_menu {
 font-family: Nunito;  /* google webfont nunito */
 min-height: 60px;
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 240px;
 max-width: 1280px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 999;
 background: #613570;
}

/* menu unorderlist layout */
.Flat_mega_menu > ul {
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
}

/* menu list items layout */
.Flat_mega_menu > ul > li {
 float: right;
 height: 60px;
 width: 10%;
 border-left: 1px solid #542961;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

/* menu a tag + user_login + search_bar hover effect */
.Flat_mega_menu > ul > li:hover a,
.Flat_mega_menu ul .user_login:hover .fa.fa-user,
.Flat_mega_menu ul .search_bar:hover .fa.fa-search {
 color: #613570;
 transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
 
}

/* menu a tag layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li a {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 60px;
 font-size: 16px;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}



/* submenu display none */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu {
 display: none
}

/* submenu with four column layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 60px;
 width: 100%;
 min-height:35px;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #613570;
}

/* submenu with four column list items layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col li {
 float: right;
 width: 10%;
}

/* submenu with four column a tag layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col li a {
 color: #555658;
 text-align: left;
 white-space: normal;
 line-height: 40px;
 margin-bottom: 1px;
 font-size: 14px;
}

/* submenu with four column a tag hover effct */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col li:hover a {
 text-indent: 5px;
 color: #000000
}

/* submenu with four column title class layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col .title {
 font-size: large;
 margin: 2%;
 font-weight: bold;
}


/* mouse hover display submenus */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li:hover .submenu.one_col,
.Flat_mega_menu ul li:hover .submenu.two_col,
.Flat_mega_menu ul .search_bar:hover ul,
.Flat_mega_menu ul .user_login:hover ul,
.Flat_mega_menu ul .social_bar:hover ul,
.Flat_mega_menu ul li:hover .submenu.img_container,
.Flat_mega_menu ul li:hover .submenu.four_col {
 display: block;
 
 /* animation */
 animation: display_submenus 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
 -webkit-animation: display_submenus 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
 -moz-animation: display_submenus 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
 -ms-animation: display_submenus 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
 -o-animation: display_submenus 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
}

/* second level submenu hover effect */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.one_col li:hover > .submenu.one_col {
 display: block;
 
 /* animation */
 animation: display_submenus_second 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
 -webkit-animation: display_submenus_second 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
 -moz-animation: display_submenus_second 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
 -ms-animation: display_submenus_second 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
 -o-animation: display_submenus_second 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
}

/* checkbox button layout */
.Flat_mega_menu .mobile_button,
.Flat_mega_menu .fa.fa-bars {
 display:none;
}


/* default animation keyframes */
@keyframes display_submenus {
 0% {
opacity:0
}
 100% {
opacity:1
}
}

/* animation for chrome and safari */
@-webkit-keyframes display_submenus {
 0% {
opacity:0
}
 100% {
opacity:1
}
}

/* animation for firefox */
@-moz-keyframes display_submenus {
 0% {
opacity:0
}
 100% {
opacity:1
}
}

/* animation for internet explorer 10+ */
@-ms-keyframes display_submenus {
 0% {
opacity:0
}
 100% {
opacity:1
}
}

/* animation for opera */
@-o-keyframes display_submenus {
 0% {
opacity:0
}
 100% {
opacity:1
}
}

/* second level submenus default animation */
@keyframes display_submenus_second {
 0% {
opacity:0
}
 100% {
opacity:1
}
}


@media screen and (max-width:768px){
/* menu unorderlist layout */
.Flat_mega_menu > ul {
 height: auto;
 position:relative;
}

/* menu list items layout */
.Flat_mega_menu > ul > li {
 float: none;
 height: 60px;
 width: 100%;
 border-left: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #542961;
 position:relative;
}

/* submenu with four column layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col {
 display: none;
 z-index:999;
 left: 0px;
 top: 60px;
}

/* submenu with four column a tag layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col li a {
 width:auto;
}

/* submenu with four column title class layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col .title{
 margin-bottom: 16px;
}
/* mobile button layout */
.Flat_mega_menu .mobile_button{
 opacity:0;
}

/* mobile buton + fontawesome icon layout */
.Flat_mega_menu .mobile_button,
.Flat_mega_menu .fa.fa-bars {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 z-index: 999;
 height: 60px;
 width: 9%;
 cursor:pointer;
 min-width: 60px;
}

/* fontawesome icon layout */
.Flat_mega_menu .fa.fa-bars:before{
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-size: 40px; 
 top: 10px;
 position: relative;
 left: 15px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:592px){

/* submenu with four column list items layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col li {
 float: left;
 width: 42%;
 margin-right: 1%;
 margin-left: 5%;
}

/* submenu with four column title class layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col .title {
 margin: 2% 1% 2% 5%;
}

/* submenu with four column title class layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col .title:nth-child(3),
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col .title:nth-child(4) {
 display:none;
}

/* submenu with four column title class layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col .title{
 margin-bottom: 26px;
}
}
.hoverdown:hover {
    content:'';
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 20px #e15915;
    border-left: solid 20px transparent;
    border-right: solid 20px transparent;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>


<div class="Flat_mega_menu">

<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>   <!-- fontawesome mobile button icon -->
<input class="mobile_button" type="checkbox">  

 <ul>

     <li class="hoverdown"><a href="#">More</a>
         <ul class="submenu four_col">
                
                <li><a href="#">Submneu</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>

<!-- mega menu end -->

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: there's no javascript or jquery in the question, and really, none should be required for such a simple task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the styles of the `.hoverdown`, your `<li>` itself on hover, that is the reason your not able to achieve the arrow effect.

Instead you need to **add** an element on hover & not edit the existing element's styles on hover(perhaps using `:after` pseudo element)

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/BLAPQZ)

Just replace your `.hoverdown:hover` to the one below

```
.hoverdown:hover:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border: 12px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    right: 4%;
}
```

Also another issue I noticed is your changing the color of the `<a>` on hover to the same color as the background, hence it looks like its hiding on `<li>` hover, change/override that to

```
.Flat_mega_menu > ul > li:hover a {
  color: white; //NOT #613570
}
```

**Updated:**

To show the arrows below each `<li>`, then add the below styles **(keep incrementing 10% for subsequent `<li>`)** - Above Codepen updated

```
.hoverdown:nth-child(2):hover:after {
  right: 14%;
}

.hoverdown:nth-child(3):hover:after {
  right: 24%;
}
...
```

This approach is not ideal, as the best way to do this is by changing the entire logic of how your menu has been built, making the `<li>` `position: relative` & then the `:after` to be `position:absolute` to the parent `<li>` & also some good amount of change to your submenu as well (if you want to re-consider the logic) :-)

Comment: but the arrow shows in general with div : absolute; i want to show the arrow specialy in bottom of each li that i hovered? is there a solution for that?

Comment: Yeah sure, in that case you might need to change the whole logic of how you are building your menu. Since it might be too much now, you can do what I have mentioned above to get what you want. Let me know if you are facing any other issues.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this if i understand you correclty:

[Example](http://codepen.io/Strs/pen/mAxjOQ)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="Flat_mega_menu">

<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>          <!-- fontawesome mobile button icon -->
<input class="mobile_button" type="checkbox">       

    <ul>

        <li class="hoverdown">
            <a href="#">More1</a>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
            <ul class="submenu four_col"> 
                <li><a href="#">Submneu1</a></li>
            </ul>
      </li>
        <li class="hoverdown">
            <a href="#">More2</a>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
            <ul class="submenu four_col"> 
                <li><a href="#">Submneu2</a></li>
            </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- mega menu end -->

</body>

</html>
```

Css code:

```
/* body layout */
body {
    background:#1b1c20;
}

/* flat mega menu layout start */
.Flat_mega_menu ul,
.Flat_mega_menu li,
.Flat_mega_menu a,
.Flat_mega_menu p,
.Flat_mega_menu i {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* mega menu layout */
.Flat_mega_menu {
    font-family: Nunito;        /* google webfont nunito */
    min-height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 240px;
    max-width: 1280px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #613570;
}

/* menu unorderlist layout */
.Flat_mega_menu > ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}

/* menu list items layout */
.Flat_mega_menu > ul > li {
    float: right;
    height: 60px;
    width: 10%;
    border-left: 1px solid #542961;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/* menu a tag + user_login + search_bar hover effect */
.Flat_mega_menu > ul > li:hover a,
.Flat_mega_menu ul .user_login:hover .fa.fa-user,
.Flat_mega_menu ul .search_bar:hover .fa.fa-search {
    color: #613570;
    transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;

}

/* menu a tag layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}



/* submenu display none */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu {
    display: none
}

/* submenu with four column layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height:35px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #613570;
}

/* submenu with four column list items layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col li {
    float: right;
    width: 10%;
}

/* submenu with four column a tag layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col li a {
    color: #555658;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: normal;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

/* submenu with four column a tag hover effct */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col li:hover a {
    text-indent: 5px;
    color: #000000
}

/* submenu with four column title class layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col .title {
    font-size: large;
    margin: 2%;
    font-weight: bold;
}


/* mouse hover display submenus */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li:hover .submenu.one_col,
.Flat_mega_menu ul li:hover .submenu.two_col,
.Flat_mega_menu ul .search_bar:hover ul,
.Flat_mega_menu ul .user_login:hover ul,
.Flat_mega_menu ul .social_bar:hover ul,
.Flat_mega_menu ul li:hover .submenu.img_container,
.Flat_mega_menu ul li:hover .submenu.four_col {
    display: block;

    /* animation */
    animation: display_submenus 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
    -webkit-animation: display_submenus 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
    -moz-animation: display_submenus 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
    -ms-animation: display_submenus 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
    -o-animation: display_submenus 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
}

/* second level submenu hover effect */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.one_col li:hover > .submenu.one_col {
    display: block;

    /* animation */
    animation: display_submenus_second 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
    -webkit-animation: display_submenus_second 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
    -moz-animation: display_submenus_second 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
    -ms-animation: display_submenus_second 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
    -o-animation: display_submenus_second 0.2s linear 0s 1 forwards;
}

/* checkbox button layout */
.Flat_mega_menu .mobile_button,
.Flat_mega_menu .fa.fa-bars {
    display:none;
}


/* default animation keyframes */
@keyframes display_submenus {
 0% {
opacity:0
}
 100% {
opacity:1
}
}

/* animation for chrome and safari */
@-webkit-keyframes display_submenus {
 0% {
opacity:0
}
 100% {
opacity:1
}
}

/* animation for firefox */
@-moz-keyframes display_submenus {
 0% {
opacity:0
}
 100% {
opacity:1
}
}

/* animation for internet explorer 10+ */
@-ms-keyframes display_submenus {
 0% {
opacity:0
}
 100% {
opacity:1
}
}

/* animation for opera */
@-o-keyframes display_submenus {
 0% {
opacity:0
}
 100% {
opacity:1
}
}

/* second level submenus default animation */
@keyframes display_submenus_second {
 0% {
opacity:0
}
 100% {
opacity:1
}
}


@media screen and (max-width:768px){
/* menu unorderlist layout */
.Flat_mega_menu > ul {
    height: auto;
    position:relative;
}

/* menu list items layout */
.Flat_mega_menu > ul > li {
    float: none;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #542961;
    position:relative;
}

/* submenu with four column layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col {
    display: none;
    z-index:999;
    left: 0px;
    top: 60px;
}

/* submenu with four column a tag layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col li a {
    width:auto;
}

/* submenu with four column title class layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col .title{
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
/* mobile button layout */
.Flat_mega_menu .mobile_button{
    opacity:0;
}

/* mobile buton + fontawesome icon layout */
.Flat_mega_menu .mobile_button,
.Flat_mega_menu .fa.fa-bars {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 60px;
    width: 9%;
    cursor:pointer;
    min-width: 60px;
}

/* fontawesome icon layout */
.Flat_mega_menu .fa.fa-bars:before{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 40px; 
    top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 15px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:592px){

/* submenu with four column list items layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col li {
    float: left;
    width: 42%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

/* submenu with four column title class layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col .title {
    margin: 2% 1% 2% 5%;
}

/* submenu with four column title class layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col .title:nth-child(3),
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col .title:nth-child(4) {
    display:none;
}

/* submenu with four column title class layout */
.Flat_mega_menu ul li .submenu.four_col .title{
    margin-bottom: 26px;
}
}

.arrow{
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #e15915;
  display:none;
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-20px;
  margin-top:-10px;
}
.hoverdown:hover .submenu four_col{
    display:block;
}
.hoverdown:hover .arrow{
   display:block;
}
```